# Export dataframe with png thumbnails as pdf python (edited- to include code)

Tags: python, html, pandas, image, jupyter

Using the one of the answers provided here: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46107348/how-to-display-image-stored-in-pandas-dataframe][1]

I am able to call `image_formatter` function `in IPython.display` HTML function to display thumbnail pngs in the dataframe.

I now want to export this HTML formatted table to a pdf file but haven't really found any helpful links to this effect. Any help will be appreciated!

```
import glob
import random
import base64
import pandas as pd
import os

from PIL import Image
from io import BytesIO
from IPython.display import HTML


#display inline images in pandas DataFrame

#source: https://www.kaggle.com/stassl/displaying-inline-images-in-pandas-dataframe

pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', None)

def get_thumbnail(path):
    i = Image.open(path)
    return i

def image_base64(im):
    if isinstance(im, str):
        im = get_thumbnail(im)
    with BytesIO() as buffer:
        im.save(buffer, 'png')
        return base64.b64encode(buffer.getvalue()).decode()

def image_formatter(im):
    return f'<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,{image_base64(im)}">'
```

To implement the above functions:

```
data = *path to csv containing a series of png paths & other details*
df=pd.DataFrame(data)
cols_2_keep= ['patient_id', "exam_id", "file_path"]
df = df[cols_2_keep]

images= HTML(df[['patient_id', "exam_id","file"]].to_html(formatters={'file': image_formatter}, escape=False))
```

```
#call images to look at HTML display
images
```

This, as expected, displays the images within the dataframe. What I'm now trying to do is export this dataframe (with images in place) into a `pdf` file.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Thank you. Please see the updated question with code.