# Django: Downloaded image won't open

Tags: python, django, dataframe, temporary-files

I am currently working on a Django app that allows me to download an image while only storing the image as a temporary file. My Django app is running on a server while I am accessing the website through a local windows machine. While I am able to download the image, the file will not open. For example, Windows Photos says that "It appears we don't support this file format". Is there something wrong with the code that would cause this problem?

**Views.py**

```
def download_png(request, study):
    Names(study) #Function to retrieve (name) variable
    Retrieve(study) #Function to retrieve (data) variable
    BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
    pngfilename = str(name) + "_" + str(current_time) + ".png"
    filepath = BASE_DIR + '/polls/graphics/' + pngfilename
    temp, filepath = tempfile.mkstemp(suffix='.png')
    with open(temp, 'w') as f:
        f = df2img.plot_dataframe(data)
        df2img.save_dataframe(fig=f, filename=filepath)
    response = HttpResponse(temp, content_type=mimetypes.guess_type(filepath))
    response['Content-Disposition'] = "attachment; filename=%s" % pngfilename
    return response
```

Update 06/30/22:
Thank you for all the help. It turns out it is better to use FileResponse rather than HttpResponse when downloading a file Here's what the updated code looks like:

```
def download_png(request, study):
    Names(study)
    Retrieve(study)
    pngfilename = str(name) + "_" + str(current_time) + ".png"
    mime_type, _ = mimetypes.guess_type(pngfilename)
    fig = df2img.plot_dataframe(data)
    df2img.save_dataframe(fig=fig, filename=pngfilename)
    response = FileResponse(open(pngfilename, 'rb'), content_type=mime_type)
    response['Content-Disposition'] = "attachment; filename=%s" % pngfilename
    os.remove(pngfilename)
    return response
```

Comment: the df2img suggest the following:
`fig = df2img.plot_dataframe(df, fig_size=(500, 140))

df2img.save_dataframe(fig=fig, filename="plot1.png")`

i'd start updating your code accordingly 
https://pypi.org/project/df2img/

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't work. Still says I can't open the file.

Comment: are you sure this is not just a window problem? have you tried p.e. opening with some online tool? 
The dataframe is correclty showing? I mean are you seeing the right image on screen before downloading it?

Comment: I tried repairing with some online tool and it didn't work. The dataframe image is being saved in the filepath and I can view the image in there. (For reference the filepath is on a server while I am downloading it onto my local machine.) However, when I download it, the file won't appear.

Comment: if you're still stuck here you may try working on a workaround such as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46107348/how-to-display-image-stored-in-pandas-dataframe ,I'm sorry i have no further evidences to give you :(

Comment: For anyone still following, I believe I've narrowed the problem to something wrong while downloading the file. After checking the binary code for the downloaded file, there isn't any data written in the file while prior to download the image is completely fine.

Comment: well it's just something, at least since there is plenty of docs on the best way to download a file in django. never give up pal!