# How to display Base64 images in EXCEL (xlsx) using Python \ Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, excel

I've add a Base64 image in every cell in excel (.xlsx)  worksheet. I'm  take as reference: [this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46107348/how-to-display-image-stored-in-pandas-dataframe). I can be able to export in html format and dispay in table all images for each rows. **But how i can to do this in excel with similar output below?**

In this moment my excel file contains: `<PIL.PngImagePlugin.PngImageFile image mode=RGB size=100x150 at 0x24C80E54890>`

[image]

Comment: You should show us your code.  There are a dozen ways to create Excel spreadsheets, and we don't know which one you're using.

Answer (score -2):

could you please try this?:

from PIL import Image
from IPython.display import display

image_object =<PIL.PngImagePlugin.PngImageFile image mode=RGB size=100x150 at 0x24C80E54890>

display(image_object)

Comment: You didn't try this, did you?  That string is not an image object.  It's just the representation of an image object from his other script.  This won't work, and you should delete it before you collect downvotes.